# How to get selected text of drop-down list in Kendo UI jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI jQuery version `2019.2.514` . I have code snippet

```
<input id="skuCode" name="skuCode" style="width: 100%;"/>
<input id="productName" name="productName" style="width: 100%;"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/sku_json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 30
        });
        // create DropDownList from input HTML element
        $("#skuCode").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,
            filter: "contains",
            index: 0,
            change: onChange
        });
    });

    // Set selected text value of Drop-down list --> value of input productName.
    function onChange() {
        // document.getElementById("productName").value =  document.getElementById("skuCode").value; // Return selected value of drop-down list
        // document.getElementById("productName").value =  document.getElementById("accountObjectCode").text; // I try something like this, but not work.
    }
</script>
```

Web page has 2 inputs: `skuCode` is a drop-down list. `productName` is a input textbox. When `skuCode` has event `onChange`, I want set value of textbox `productName` automatically (equal the text label of selected drop-down list, not value of selected drop-down list), but still allow user edit. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with help of following method.

Value method : Gets or sets the value of the DropDownList.
text method :  Gets or sets the text of the DropDownList.

Here is example :

```
<input id="skuCode" name="skuCode" style="width: 100%;"/>
<input id="productName" name="productName" style="width: 100%;"/>
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
$("#productName").kendoDropDownList({
   dataSource: [
   { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
   { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
],
dataTextField: "name",
dataValueField: "id",
change: onChange
});
function onChange(e) {
//  You can do with this also
//   $("#skuCode").val($("#productName").data("kendoDropDownList").text());
     $("#skuCode").val(e.sender.text());
 };
});
```

Let me know if anything incorrect.